# Set-AzureDeployment Powershell cmdlet failing with error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: powershell, azure

On my TFS 2013 Build server, on post-build event to trigger a PowerShell script to deploy the build to my Azure subscription. It was running fine till yesterday and started failing all of sudden. When I run the PS script manually, it works fine (as long as the PS console is opened as Administrator).

The error occurs at Set-AzureDeployment cmdlet and I do set and select my azure subscription before running this cmdlet. It occurs to be a permission issue as the script runs fine when triggered with admin rights but not sure why all of sudden it started happening. Any hints?

I have copied the full error stack here:

An error occurred while sending the request.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage.StorageAccountOperationsExtensions.Get(IStorageAccountOperations operations, String serviceName) in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-m
si\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\ManagementLibraries\StorageManagement\StorageManagementClient.cs:line 1895
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.WindowsAzureSubscription.GetCloudStorageAccount() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.U
tilities\Common\WindowsAzureSubscription.cs:line 190
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.StorageCloudCmdletBase`1.GetStorageAccountFromSubscription() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\C
ommands.Storage\Common\StorageCloudCmdletBase.cs:line 176
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.StorageCloudCmdletBase`1.GetCloudStorageAccount() in c:\workspace\workspace\build-azure-sdk-tools-msi\WindowsAzurePowershell\src\Commands.Sto
rage\Common\StorageCloudCmdletBase.cs:line 81

Comment: Can you check the day/time on your machines and the server? Maybe there is some skew?